# Connecting to multiple Windows RDP via Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, windows-10, remote-desktop, port-forwarding

I'm sorry but i always trying to find solutions, search forums etc. but first time i'm lost. This should be easy :( but soo far i fail, maybe i can't comprehend some topics.

I have Ubuntu Server 22.04 working as router for Company internal network. Working SSH inside of network and outside. But i can't manage to workaround to use windows remote desktop outside a network (inside working without a problem). I unlocked port 3389 on ISP and still nothing. Base of my searches i started wondering is it even possible ?

I want to connect about five windows computers with ability to remote desktop.

- My test computer is Windows 10 PRO.
- ISP is connected to Linux Server > Linux Server is connected to switch > Switch connected to Windows PC
- SSH to Linux via public IP is working(not via windows remote desktop but via putty).
- Inside a network i can connect to every computer with remote desktop enabled
- Linux is only text, no graphic interface(if ti helps i use webmin)

I imagine that this should be easy, soo far i can't find any solution.
I will be greatly appreciated for help.

Cheers

Comment: So you need to set up port forwarding?

Comment: Thanks for reply. You mean by iptables ?

Comment: I think there are multiple ways to do it. I've only set up port forwarding using a router instead of Ubuntu. You might be able to use ufw instead of iptables, though. As mentioned in the other answer, it's best to [check if the port is open first](https://portchecker.co/). I was thinking that you might get better response or you might have more luck searching for how to do port forwarding with Ubuntu if that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is a firewall maybe blocking port 3389? Try telnet ip 3389 and see if you can connect. How did you verify that RDP is enabled (maybe raise a ticket to let the ISP verify)? Do you have enough permissions to connect with RDP (Remote Desktop User or local admin).

Sounds like a routing issue, I think you need to figure out how to translate your connection coming from external to the internal ip's of the windows pc's. But in my opnion this isn't a solution I would recommend to do. if you want multiple users to work with Remote Desktop, deploy a Remote Desktop or use Azure Virtual Desktop

Comment: First of all i checked ISP router, to be sure if unlocking port works. I unlocked port 22 before, checked by telnet and website given by mchid, it is unlocked. Just to be sure i remove unlocked port and checked again, blocked, added again same port, unlocked. 

Move to Linux, ufw was disabled, i enabled it and tested port 22, blocked. Added port 22, checked and it work. 
Now when i'm trying to unlock any other port (1069,3389) it is blocked :(
I'm trying some luck with iptables with uwu and router but still no effect.

Comment: I appreciated all help and general sense of direction, thank you.
Still stuck but at least i have something.

Comment: Does your firewall allow the connection now: sudo iptables-save | grep <a TCP port number> . If possible also provide the whole iptables config with: sudo iptables -L

Comment: And if not already done enable some logging: https://tecadmin.net/enable-logging-in-iptables-on-linux/